# Error: Failed to parse src "//_next/static/media/dbl-cheese-burger.4ac73aa3.png" on `next/image`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, next.js13

Take a look at this please

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "@/data/data.json";

interface propsData {
  dish: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    image: any;
  };
}

function Card(props: propsData) {
  const [dish, setDish] = useState(props.dish);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await import(`../../assets/${dish.image}`); // change relative path to suit your needs
        console.warn(response);
        setDish({ ...dish, image: response?.default?.src });
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    };
    fetchImage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div >
      <Image width={150} height={150} alt={dish.name} src={dish.image}></Image>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

the dish.image  is a string, the weird thing is that when I swap the next Image compo to a normal "img" tag, it works but when I use the Image compo which is better for scaling and optimization, it returns this error "Error: Failed to parse src "//_next/static/media/dbl-cheese-burger.4ac73aa3.png" on `next/image`, protocol-relative URL (//) must be changed to an absolute URL (http:// or https://)"

At data.json file is where the image name comes from it exists in props.dish.image, for example, "burger.png", knowing that all my assets are in an assets folder. please let me know if there is another way to import the image from the folder that is going to work in Next Image component. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fetch image.
You can move dish images into public/assets and set next/image src as

```
src="/assets/${dish.image}"
```

Comment: it is working but can i move all the assets there ?